# Hiding model and collection save and fetch URLs in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

This must be a very stupid question because nobody else is asking it. I'm using Backbone.js with URLs for views like website.com/#article/12. To fetch the article, there is a GET request to /article/12. How do I redirect or 404 when the user goes to website.com/article/12 (without the hash) and sees the requested JSON in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server should just respond to different HTTP requests in different ways based on the `Accept` headers.

On your server, if the request comes in with `Accept: application/json` then your app should return the JSON. Otherwise (like if it's `Accept: text/html`) you can return the HTML view you want them to see, redirect, or whatever. How you do this would just depend on what language/framework you're using, but should be relatively easy.

Ideally you'd use the same URL for the client view and drop the `#` tag (check out HTML5 pushState which Backbone.js supports nicely.)